# how to read email using node-pop3

Tags: node.js, meteor, pop3

I am using the package node-pop3 in my Meteor App.
I am successful in RETR command. I get the stream and the info. The info have information only about how many octets.

How can I read the message in email? I am also using mailparser. But I don't know what will I send to mailparser. Is it the whole stream?

Here is the package for mailparser. 
https://github.com/andris9/mailparser

The problem here is, how can I read email using mailparser? What will I pass to,

```
mailparser.write(?);
```

is it the stream?

Answer (score 1):

```
import * as mailparser from 'mailparser';
import * as PopNode from 'node-pop3';

//--- initialise emailobject:
const pop3Command = new PopNode({
  user: 'email address',
  password: 'password',
  host: 'hostname'
});

let emailsList = await pop3Command.UIDL();  // fetch list of all emails
let msg = await pop3Command.RETR(msgNumber);  // fetch the email content
let parsedEmail = await simpleParser(msg);  // convert into readable email content
```

Answer (score 0):

Things probably have changed since this question was posted, but at least as of version 0.8.0, node-pop3's RETR returns a string (using a nice helper function in that package called stream2String).  That string can be passed to simpleParser to get the parsed contents.

```
import {simpleParser} from 'mailparser';
let msg = await pop3Command.RETR(msgNumber);
let parsedEmail = await simpleParser(msg);
```